# ChartJs annotation does not work with Tooltip

Tags: chart.js

I have a requirement where on hover i need to show one horizontal line like in below fiddle.
but tool-tip is getting disappeared once on hover horizontal line is drawn.
Can anyone help how i can get tool-tip along  with horizontal line.

Please note in below fiddle we have issue on hover it takes time but in my actual project hover is working fine , i just have issue that after hover tool-tip does not work after some time.
https://jsfiddle.net/h8ow63be/

```
var option = {
  legend: false,
  title: {
    display: true,
  },
  onHover: function(evt) {
    var item = myLineChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
    if (item.length) {
     updateChart(data.datasets[0].data[item[0]._index].y)
    }
  },
  animation: {
                duration: 0
            },
  annotation: {
   annotations: lines
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      id: 'x-axis',
      type: 'linear',
      position: 'bottom',
      ticks: {
        max: 12,
        min: 1,
        stepSize: 1
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      id: 'y-axis',
      type: 'linear',
    }],
  }

};
```